# AltBeacon search for GATT services

Tags: android, bluetooth, altbeacon, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have GATT server on iOS device (and the same on Android) which has 2 characteristics - one for read and one for write.
How can I find this device with AltBeacon on Android? I don't know should I use special parser layout or it isn't possible to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AltBeacon is an open specification for a Bluetooth LE beacon -- **it actually doesn't use GATT at all**, and operates at a lower level of raw manufacturer Bluetooth LE advertisements.  The Android Beacon Library, which is hosted at AltBeacon.org can be used to detect a wide variety of Bluetooth LE beacons and transmit these beacon types.

While the Android Beacon Library will detect certain beacon types that are based on GATT service advertisements like Eddystone, **it is not designed as a general purpose GATT service detector.**  **Using the library to try and detect a GATT service will probably not prove very useful.**  Instead, it is better to use Android's built-in Bluetooth LE scanning APIs.  You can see an example of how to do that in the "Finding BLE Devices" section of [this page.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

Full Disclosure:  I am the lead developer of the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) open source project.

Comment: Thank you! Now I use Android's and iOS built-in Bluetooth LE scanning APIs. But wanted to replace it with AltBeacon. Is it possible to transmitting as a Beacon on iOS device (with AltBeacon)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  iOS restricts advertising Bluetooth LE data byres to only the iBeacon format.  This makes it impossible for an iOS device to transmit any beacon format (e.g.AltBeacon or Eddystone) or to transmit iBeacon using anything other than built-in iOS SDKs.